# How to create 1 second video files from original

Tags: ffmpeg

i'm trying to create 1 second video files from the original using ffmpeg.  i'm using this command:

`ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:00:01 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 output%03d.mp4`

it creates the files but many of the output files are longer than 1 second duration.  is there a better or more accurate way to create these 1 second segments?

Comment: a) `segment_time` has to be equal to desired segment length. b) your video should have keyframes 1 second apart.

Comment: whoops -- my mistake.  i changed the segment length time and it still didn't help.

what i'm doing now is, I created a loop that that loops over the total duration and i'm calling ffmpeg.  this works but this is painfully slow.  is there another way?

`-i {inputFile} -ss {index} -t 1 {outputFile}`